# Load class properties using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently setting the properties in a class like this:

```
MyClass _Temp = (from x in entities.someTable 
    select new MyClass {
        PropertyONE = x.PropertyONE,
        PropertyTWO = x.PropertyTWO
    }).FirstOrDefault();

this.PropertyONE = _Temp.PropertyONE;
this.PropertyTWO = _Temp.PropertyTWO;
```

But i'm thinking there has to be a better way than creating another instance of the class as a placeholder just to end up populating the real one - something like this?

```
this = (from x in entities.someTable 
    select 
        PropertyONE = x.PropertyONE,
        PropertyTWO = x.PropertyTWO
    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Any ideas?

*** EDIT: MORE INFO ****
How I'm using this:

In an MVC controller I have:

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
{
    MyClass model = new MyClass(id);
    Return View(model);
}
```

And in the constructor of "MyClass" I have the code above that I want it to 'preload' the class (it's properties) with data to display on the view.

Hope this explains it better.

Comment: Are you simply looking at mapping properties of an entity to properties of a domain object?

Comment: Updated the question to include how I want to apply this.

Comment: You can manually map the data as per Scorpi0's answer. You can also use AutoMapper if you need to do data shaping etc during your mapping process (obviously it's a bit overkill for a simple Prop -> Prop mapping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var _Temp = entities.someTable.Select(x=> new{
                                               PropertyONE = x.PropertyONE,
                                               PropertyTWO = x.PropertyTWO 
                                             }).FirstOrDefault();
this.PropertyONE = _Temp.PropertyONE;
this.PropertyTWO = _Temp.PropertyTWO;
```

Comment: This creates an anonymous type with the PropertyONE and PropertyTWO properties (`new {}` = anonymous type) whereas your original was using an instance of the target type

Comment: @Losbear: It creates an anonymous type, rather than another instance of your class.

Comment: you're right - my bad.  yea I guess I could do it this way.  I was hoping to set the values straight into the class instead of setting it to a temp object first.  this will work better than what i'm doing, I agree.

Comment: I don't think 'setting the values straight into the class' makes sense since you need some sort of mapping specification to tell it which entity property maps to which class property, even if it is just a name matching exercise. If you *really* need to you can use AutoMapper

Comment: thanks guys - the automapper is more than I need for this problem, so i'm just going to use an anon type instead of setting it to a copy of the class - must more efficient. Not sure why I didn't think of this - I guess that's what SO is for :)  thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it should be simpler:

```
var first = entities.someTable.FirstOrDefault();
if(first != null)
{
    this.PropertyONE = first.PropertyONE;
    this.PropertyTWO = first.PropertyTWO;
}
```

---

Edit : split you code in layer:

**Data Access Layer**

```
public static Entity GetById(int id)
{
    using(var entities = new MyEntities())
    {
        return entities.someTable
                       .FirstOrDefault(row => row.Id == id);
    }
}
```

**Controller Layer**

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
{
    MyClass model;
    // call the DAL
    var entity = DataAccess.GetById(id);

    // call the model
    if(entity != null)
    {
        model = new MyClass(entity);
    }
    else
    {
        model = null;
    }
    Return View(model);
}
```

**Model Layer**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(Entity entity)
    {
        this.PropertyONE = entity.PropertyONE;
        this.PropertyTWO = entity.PropertyTWO;
    }
}
```

Comment: yea I had this at one point, but then I had to add more custom lookups to the class (had to populate a couple Lists().  I have something similar to this but I pass (MyClass model) as a parameter.  That's why I'm stuck where I am, because I was trying to set "model" properties using what you have above as a "return".  I think I might just go with Roar's suggestion of setting it to an anon type then filling the model manually.  it's more efficient than what I currently have.